# Mavericks Random Spinning Beach Ball appears for less than a second and then goes away

Tags: macos

Ever since upgrading to Mavericks v 10.9.0, the swirly beach ball of death shows up randomly for a split second, even if nothing is currently loading.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem or is it a known bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I have seen this on two different machines. Its definitely a bug.

You can see a mention of it in lots of places, including here:

http://www.imore.com/round-table-review-os-x-mavericks